# PHP: PDO if user exists check doesn't work

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I'm new to PHP, I created User class/object which has a function that checks for user, it returns `$stmt->rowCount()` but when I check for it in code it just skip it, register the user..

Here is the code:

```
if(empty($name_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)) {   
            if($user->doesUserExist($email) === 0) {
                    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $user->register($username, $name, $email, $password); 
                } else {
                    $global_err = "Email is already taken";
                }
         }
```

Here is the function from User class:

```
public function doesUserExist($email) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email";
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount($stmt);
            return $rowcount;

        }
```

Comment: try printing function response using `var_dump($user->doesUserExist($email))` and paste response here

Comment: It returns `int(0)` although there is the email in DB

Comment: Solved, needed `count(*)` in query ..

Answer (score 0):

instead of `===` in your condition of `if($user->doesUserExist($email) === 0)` try to change to `==` 
and then try to change your method like this:

```
public function doesUserExist($email) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "';";
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $rowcount = count($stmt->fetchAll());
            return $rowcount;

 }
```

Comment: try to change your method in to that one that i'm updated it.

Comment: No, I have `var_dump(doesUserExist($email)` and shows `int(0)` even when I hardcode the email on the beginning of the page..

Comment: Should have used `$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = :email";`..Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should Try

Call the function

```
$checkemail=$api->checkuseremail($email);
if($checkemail)
{
    echo $mail_check;
}
```

and define your function like this

```
public function checkuseremail($email)
{
    $db=getDB();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("Select id from table_name where email=:email");
    $stmt->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($count)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will return email are already exist or not